Language code syntax to display variant characters
This is a feature request to implement what's already given at Japanese SE.
This is an important feature when discussing variant Chinese characters (such as the question here), as Han Unification has forced regional variations into one codepoint, making it difficult to address language-specific variants in Chinese character shape without resorting to images.

may i ask, what’s the definition of “variant character”?
from the link of japanese language stackexchange:

when the same Unicode codepoint has different glyphs depending on the language code selected

doesn’t it depend on the region / language settings of the operating system, and fonts installed; that apps chose the font to display the glyph of particular code point?
i’m curious.
case 1: 幕 (u+5e55) vs 幙 (u+5e59), the 教育部異體字字典 stated that 幕 is regular, and 幙 is variant 

< https://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/rbt/word_attribute.rbt?quote_code=QTAxMTg1>
another case is 並 (u+4e26) vs 竝 (u+7add)
< https://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/rbt/word_attribute.rbt?quote_code=QTAwMDE4>
how would the feature requested handle these two case?
have fun :)

doesn’t it depend on the region / language settings of the operating system, and fonts installed sure, if someone wants to modify their font so that every character appears as "A", then they can do that. But as with most things, default operating systems come with preset fonts for different language locales, and most browsers will intelligently choose the correct font. For the vast majority of people, the "incorrect character shape" is not on the user end.

As to case 1: 幕 (u+5e55) vs 幙 (u+5e59) and 並 (u+4e26) vs 竝 (u+7add), well they are different unicode codepoints - we are asking for a feature which chooses the shape because of differences displayed by the same unicode codepoint. See Japanese Meta SE's link for the example 直.

then, it’s not relevant to variant character. it’s just a request to provide info for os / browsers to use a regional preferred fonts.

What is or isn't "variant characters" is not decided by its Unicode codepoint. Shape differences noticeable to learners would easily qualify for variant characters.

i see, thanks for the clarification
