Is there a way to typeset the variants of 起?
I'd like to edit both the Mainland and Taiwanese 起 variants into the title of Can 起 be written in two different ways? to make it clear what the question is about from reading the title.  However, I don't know how to do it.  Maybe someone with Unicode skills can do this.
Question: Is there a way to typeset the variants of 起?

This is part of the motivation for https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1668/language-code-syntax-to-display-variant-characters

I believe 起 will display based on the fonts that are installed on your computer and the fonts that are called on by your browser.
There is one common Unicode point: 8D77
Unifiable variant variants are merged and it is up to the fonts to do the work of sorting.

What you can do is write their compositions:

⿺走己
⿺走巳

Wiktionary also writes the compositions with area of usage:

⿺走巳(HT) or ⿺走己(GJKV))


H = Hong Kong
T = Taiwan
G = Mainland
J = Japan
K = Korea
V = Vietnam


If we had more control on the site we could use a WOFF (web open font format) and then import a @font-face and set a span class for the sites style CSS. Then you could call you span class to dictate the font you wanted displayed on all devices for specific characters. But, this can be quite resource intensive.

Thanks!  That works.
